# Compare two text files and output lines that are present in file1 but not in file2

Tags: powershell

I need to compare 2 text files. Here is an example:

```
PS > type file1
1
2
3
4
5

PS > type file2
3
4
5
6
```

Now, I need to find lines that are present in file1 but not in file2.

In `Linux/bash`, I can do this with:

```
$ comm -23 file1 file2
1
2
```

How can I do this in `PowerShell`?

Comment: So... what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: Freeform text or is this structured data like a pair of csv files? Are you looking for word by word differences or whole lines? Your question is a bit vague.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the compare-object scriptlet to find the difference.

```
PS > compare-object (get-content file1) (get-content file2)
InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
6           =>
1           <=
2           <=
```

The difference is in form of array of .net objects. So you filter within that array and select only those entries where side-indicator is `<=`. And then print only the `InputObject` field of the object.

```
PS > compare-object (get-content file1) (get-content file2)  | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
1
2
```